# $project in $lookup mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have a query, that use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to "join" two models, after this i use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to select olny the fields that i need, but my $project brings an arrray of objects (`user_detail`) that contains more data that i need. I want only two fields (`scheduleStart` and `scheduleEnd`) of my result.

**My query:**

```
 User.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,      
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          cpf: "$cpf",      
          phone: "$phone",
          email: "$email",
          birthday: "$birthday",
          lastName: "$lastname"      
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: "$services"
        },    
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        localField: "_id.phone",
        foreignField: "customer.phone",
        as: "user_detail"
      }  
    },  
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        name: 1,
        cpf: 1,      
        phone: 1,
        email: 1,
        birthday: 1,
        totalServices: 1,
        totalValue: { $sum : "$user_detail.value" },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        user_detail: 1
      }
    },
```

**Result of query:**

```
count: 1
totalServices: 0
totalValue: 73
user_detail: Array(2)
0:
...
paymentMethod: 0
paymentValue: "0"
scheduleDate: "2018-10-02"
scheduleEnd: "2018-10-02 08:40"
scheduleStart: "2018-10-02 08:20"
status: 3
store: "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b"
updated: "2018-11-27T13:30:21.116Z"
1:
...
paymentMethod: 0
paymentValue: "0"
scheduleDate: "2018-11-27"
scheduleEnd: "2018-11-27 00:13"
scheduleStart: "2018-11-27 00:03"
status: 2
store: "5b16cceb56a44e2f6cd0324b"
updated: "2018-11-27T19:33:39.498Z"
_id:
birthday: "1992-03-06"
email: "csantosgrossi@gmail.com"
id: "5bfed8bd70de7a383855f09e"
name: "Chris Santos G"
phone: "11969109995"
...
```

**Result that i need:**

```
count: 1
totalServices: 0
totalValue: 73
user_detail: Array(2)
0:
scheduleEnd: "2018-10-02 08:40"
scheduleStart: "2018-10-02 08:20"
1:
scheduleEnd: "2018-11-27 00:13"
scheduleStart: "2018-11-27 00:03"

_id:
birthday: "1992-03-06"
email: "csantosgrossi@gmail.com"
id: "5bfed8bd70de7a383855f09e"
name: "Chris Santos G"
phone: "11969109995"
...
```

How can i do this with my query?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) 3.6 syntax to [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the fields inside the  [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "schedules",
    "let": { "id": "$_id.phone" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$customer.phone", "$$id"] }}},
      { "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "user_detail"
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 11):

For version of mongo version > 3.6 this query should work for you:

```
 User.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,      
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          cpf: "$cpf",      
          phone: "$phone",
          email: "$email",
          birthday: "$birthday",
          lastName: "$lastname"      
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: "$services"
        },    
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        localField: "_id.phone",
        foreignField: "customer.phone",
        as: "user_detail"
      }  
    },  
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        name: 1,
        cpf: 1,      
        phone: 1,
        email: 1,
        birthday: 1,
        totalServices: 1,
        totalValue: { $sum : "$user_detail.value" },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        user_detail: {
            scheduleEnd: 1,
            scheduleStart: 1,
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Having to add *all* the parent fields to the projection is such a pain though...