# $lookup or joins is not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, lookup

I want to get another datatable field along with response data, as like join ($lookup) in mongodb, but its giving empty output of join table. Here is my code..

```
 Releases.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "release_date": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 10 },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "companies",     // actual schema name Company
    "localField": "company_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "companyinfo"
  } },

])
```

its giving the empty array companyinfo, and in the schema I create " Company " but in database, its automatic change it with " companies "

here is sample document

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
"company_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"heading": "testing",
"description": "testing",
"key_point": "filename",
"release_date": "2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"datetime": {
    "$date": "2018-12-03T14:53:57.031Z"
},
"__v": 0,
}
```

and I want output fields {heading, description, key_point, release_date, companyinfo.company_email} only, any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Mongoose pluralize the database name so `Company` became `companies`. Now what is the type of `company_id`? Your both the `localField` and `foriegnField` type should be same. And here I can see `company_id` is a type of `String`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes you are right, here is string, so how can I do that ?

Comment: If you are using mongodb 4.0 then you can `$toString` and `$toObjectId` aggregation to convert it. Else you cannot. You have to change your schema.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, your suggestion works for me, I changed the scheme, now please let me know one more thing, I want only single field from another table not full data, how can I do that ?

Comment: You can go through my [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710203/project-in-lookup-mongodb/53710386#53710386) answer